# IIS hangs from time to time, more oftenly recently

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis, windows-server-2008-r2, applicationpoolidentity

We have a production app (ASP.NET MCV 3) running on IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise, and my problem is that, from time to time, the application becomes unresponsive. Every request made takes forever and no result is coming back from the server.
My question is this: where should I look for things going wrong, and, more importantly, what are these things.

I have full access to that machine, so if any other information may be needed (IIS/Windows logs etc etc.) I am able to provide it.

Thanks, and I hope this is not a duplicate. If so, please point me to the other post.

Latest findings: I have managed to reproduce this error on our test environment, as well, but still don't know what's causing this. This happens when two users are logged in, with two different user accounts. At some point, a request is made that never completes. It doesn't give a time-out, it just says (pending) forever. Recycling the app pool solves this problem. Any thoughts?

Updates: it seems to be an app pool problem: when the test application is moved to the DefaultAppPool (using, therefore, ApplicationPoolIdentity) the glitch appears no more. When I switch back to MyAppPool (using NetworkService as a user), the application starts freezing up again. So, changing to DefaultAppPool should be the correct move. Unfortunately, this doesn't (rather cannot) apply on the production server. There, the user must be a specific one in order to perform some file uploading/downloading to/from a private NAS. How could I possibly make things work from here? Code user impersonating? Clone ApplicationPoolIdentity user permissions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it turns out that there was some kind of permissions issue, but i still haven't found the source. What I did, instead, was making the application pool identities for the test and prod app (Network Service for test, specific accounts for prod) members of the IIS_IUSRS group, and we are now OK.